# Bash: How to apply two string operations in one line?

Tags: string, bash

I'd like to change the path and extension of a file in a variable at once e.g. do the following

```
for F in $( find /foo/bar -name "*.ext" ); do 
  Ftmp=${F%.ext}
  cp $F ${Ftmp//bar/b0r}.tmp 
done
```

without a temporary variable

Can two string operations be applied at once with bash only means?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the Bash [**temporary variable**](http://techpaste.com/2012/05/bash-shell-built-in-shell-variables-scripting)

```
$_    Temporary variable; initialized to pathname of script or program
      being executed. Later, stores the last argument of previous command.
      Also stores name of matching MAIL ﬁle during mail checks.
```

```bsh
for F in $( find /foo/bar -name "*.ext" )
do
  : ${F%.ext}
  cp $F ${_//bar/b0r}.tmp
done
```

Comment: Interesting! I never knew this existed. It's not documented in the bash man page, at least as of bash 4.2.

Comment: I tried this without the loop and `${F%.ext}` gives `bash: command not found`

Comment: @mbxzxz Are you including the colon in front? It's the "do nothing" command. You need some sort of command, or bash will try to interpret the variable itself as a command. The colon command does nothing (except quit with an exit status of 0, like the "true" command), but its final (and in this case only) argument gets passed on to the temporary variable, per the description in this answer, and the bash manual -- see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280453/understand-the-meaning-of) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do it like without a temporary variable:

```
for F in $( find /foo/bar -name "*.ext" ); do 
     cp $F "$(sed 's/\.[^.]\+$/.tmp/;s/bar/b0r/' <<< $F)" 
done
```

But that's two new process. With simple variable expansion I think you need that temo variable.

**Edit**: thanks to [@glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099233/bash-how-to-apply-two-string-oprations-in-one-line/9099888#comment11431042_9099888) now it's one extra process.

**Edit2**: `bash` only with a single variable sort of:

```
for F in $( find /foo/bar -name "*.ext" ); do 
     F=${F/.ext/}
     cp ${F}.ext ${F/bar/b0r}.tmp
done
```

Comment: you can use the bash "here-string" to remove the "echo": `cp "$F" "$(sed 's/\.[^.]\+$/.tmp/;s/bar/b0r/' <<< "$F")"`

Comment: That's not bash only. sed is not a built-in.

Comment: Yes, you are right, @Pumbaa80 I just going to edit it to bash only, with a single variable :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No.

You're talking about [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

They all take the form `${parameter...`, and a parameter is ["a name, a number or one of the special characters listed below..."](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters), so the parameter must not be itself an expression.

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you:

```
for F in $( find /foo/bar -name "*.ext" | sed 's/\.ext$//'); do 
     cp ${F}.ext ${F//bar/b0r}.tmp
done
```